# How can I map through the list and return a list of Strings that pass my validation in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart

I am beginner in flutter, "data" is a List which get from an api, when I print "nameLower" , it works but if I print "stations" it's not showing. Is the above function  returned after what?? How can I create a list of Strings from "nameLowers" , which is return from Map function.

```
static Future<List<String>> getName(String query) async {
    final data = await NetworkHelper(url: "http://34.93.58.35:3000/getStations")
        .convert2lkr();


   List<String> stations =  data.map((val){
      final queryLower = query.toLowerCase();
      final nameLower = val["stationName"].toLowerCase();
      if(nameLower.contains(queryLower)){
        print(nameLower);
        return nameLower;
      }
    }).toList();

    stations.add("Yata");
    print(stations);
    return stations;
```

result of print(nameLower)

```
I/flutter (19774): diyatalawa
I/flutter (19774): yatagama
I/flutter (19774): yatawara
I/flutter (19774): yatirawana
I/flutter (19774): yattalgoda
```

I want to create a list of the above 5 strings printed on the console. How can I create it and pass it when the function is called. query is "yat".

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not returning anything if `nameLower` does not contain the query, you implicitly  return `null`, resulting in a list with type `List<String?>` instead of `List<String>`. A better way to filter the list is as follows:

```
final queryLower = query.toLowerCase();
final stationNames = data.map((e) => e["stationName"]!.toLowerCase());
final filteredStations = stationNames.where((name) => name.contains(queryLower));
print(filteredStations);
return filteredStations.toList();
```

Comment: Not worked , filtered stations and stationName not get printed, I can't understand why is that. 'data' is printing and if I loop throught the  data and print each['stationName'],it returns me a string value ,but if i choose map function to return it is not working

Comment: This works for me where `data` is of type `List<Map<String, String>>`. What is the type of `data` and how does the data look like, besides having the property `"stationName"`

Comment: [API](http://34.93.58.35:3000/getStations) , here is that api which I called.

Comment: But what is the type of your `data` property? What does `convert2lkr()` return exactly?

Comment: `String data = response.body;`
`return jsonDecode(data);`                                                                                                             Get the body of the respond and used jsonDecode

Comment: I am guessing data is simply not the correct type.`jsonDecode` simply returns `dynamic`, So I think you need to make sure that it is at least `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`

Comment: `List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = jsonDecode(response.body);`                                       This code returns nothing if i print data in console

Comment: try `List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(jsonDecode(response.body) as List<dynamic>)`

Comment: Now it's returning data but same problem as before stationNames and filtered stations are not working

Comment: I made a small edit to the answer. I tried it in dartpad with the actual data from the API and it works. Are you sure you implemented the answer correctly?

Comment: Is there any way to send the dartpad link?? It's not working for me

Comment: https://dartpad.dev/?id=7abe863d7720e362817fc018876faad6&null_safety=true